# URL is produced each radio click, how to stop

Tags: javascript

Finally found an anchor code that puts a clickable URL where I want it, however the onclick of the radio buttons writes the URL for each click.

I need the URL to replace / reset the previous selection on each radio click so only 1 URL is ever showing - i will eventually have about 30 radio buttons - each will produce a different URL.

```js
var roomNo = ""
var phoneNo = ""
var guestPin = ""
var roomLink = ""
var createLinkNode1 = ""
var createLinkNode2 = ""
var link369 = 'https://join.meet.video.justice.gov.uk/';
var link453 = 'https://join.meet.video.justice.gov.uk/';
function H369() {
document.getElementById("roomNo").innerHTML = "CVP Room: " + "HMCTS369";
document.getElementById("phoneNo").innerHTML = "Telephone Number: " + "02920 ";
document.getElementById("guestPin").innerHTML = "Guest Pin Number: " + "4444";
document.getElementById("roomLink").innerHTML = "<b>" + "Full Clickable URL Link: " + "</b>";

createLinkNode1(link369, document.body);

function createLinkNode1(url, parent) {
    const linkTextNode = document.createTextNode(url);
  const linkNode = document.createElement('a');
  linkNode.href = url;
  linkNode.appendChild(linkTextNode);
  
  parent.appendChild(linkNode);
}
}


function H453() {           
document.getElementById("roomNo").innerHTML = "CVP Room: " + "HMCTS453";
document.getElementById("phoneNo").innerHTML = "Telephone Number: " + "02920";
document.getElementById("guestPin").innerHTML = "Guest Pin Number: " + "5555";
document.getElementById("roomLink").innerHTML = "<b>" + "Full Clickable URL Link: " + "</b>";

createLinkNode2(link453, document.body);

function createLinkNode2(url, parent) {
    const linkTextNode = document.createTextNode(url);
  const linkNode = document.createElement('a');
  linkNode.href = url;
  linkNode.appendChild(linkTextNode);
  
  parent.appendChild(linkNode);
}
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>


<input type="radio" name="CVPRoom" onclick = "H369()">HMCTS369</br>
<input type="radio" name="CVPRoom" onclick = "H453()">HMCTS453</br>

<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<p id="demo3"></p>

<div id="roomNo"></div>
<div id="phoneNo"></div>
<div id="guestPin"></div>
<div id="roomLink"></div>


<script src="CVPScripts.js">


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I had it working on my previous code version, but the anchor would put the URL at the bottom of the HTML so was useless - stupidly overwrote the code so no example to demo

Comment: Use `document.getElementById("roomLink")` instead of `document.body` in calls to `createLinkNode...` functions

Comment: Instead of creating the anchor every time, check to see if the anchor is there. If it is, set its `href` to the URL, and its `textContent` to the text you want. Otherwise, create the anchor as you are now.

Comment: In the future, you might want to redact any un-needed (potentially personal) information from your code before posting it.

Comment: The answer you chose to accept is very inefficient. Perhaps re-read my answer and consider using the techniques in that answer. I know my answer is using several complicated methods but they are recommended to update the DOM once instead of once for each radio/output element

Comment: I went with the first answer i could understand (to a degree) and get to work.
I'm sure that eventually i will understand what you advise, but for now i was looking for something I could work with and then build on.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Brentix45 See the new version I added. It does not manipulate the dom after the creation of the radios

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best way is create a object with the data, and not repeat functions that do the same thing. Create one function for each functionality and pass the data from the object to the functions.

Check this:

```js
let conferences = [
    {
    id: "369",
    input: {
      name : "CVPRoom",
      value: "HMCTS369"
    },
    info: {
        room: "HMCTS369",
      phone: "02920 376411",
      pin: "4444",
      link: "https://join.meet.video.justice.gov.uk/HMCTS/#/?conference=hmcts369@meet.video.justice.gov.uk"
    }
  },
  {
    id: "453",
    input: {
      name : "CVPRoom",
      value: "HMCTS453"
    },
    info: {
        room: "HMCTS453",
      phone: "02920 376400",
      pin: "5555"
    }
  }
]


let divInputs = document.querySelector('#inputs')
let divData = document.querySelector('#data')

conferences.forEach( c => {
    let label = document.createElement('label')
  
    let radio = document.createElement('input')
    radio.setAttribute('type', 'radio')
    radio.value = c.input.value
    radio.name = c.input.name
    radio.id = c.id
    radio.addEventListener( 'change', e=>{
      changeData( c )
    } )
    
    label.appendChild(radio)
    label.appendChild( document.createTextNode( c.input.value ) )
  divInputs.appendChild( label )
} )

function changeData( conferenceData ){
    while( divData.hasChildNodes() ){
  divData.removeChild( divData.firstChild )
  }
    let divRoom = document.createElement('div')
    divRoom.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`CVP Room: ${conferenceData.info.room}`))
  divData.appendChild( divRoom )
    let divPhone = document.createElement('div')
    divPhone.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`Telephone Number: ${conferenceData.info.phone}`))
  divData.appendChild( divPhone )
    let divPin = document.createElement('div')
    divPin.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`Guest Pin Number: ${conferenceData.info.pin}`))
  divData.appendChild( divPin )
    let aLink = document.createElement('a')
    aLink.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Full Clickable Link'))
    aLink.href = `https://join.meet.video.justice.gov.uk/HMCTS/#/?conference=${conferenceData.info.room.toLowerCase()}@meet.video.justice.gov.uk`
  divData.appendChild( aLink )
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<div id="inputs">
  
</div>

<div id="data">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you remove each node one by one and then add each node one by one - that is very inefficient

Comment: cheers for the assist, still got a lot to learn :)

Comment: @mplungjan, it's right way to use createElement instead of innerHTML. You have several advantages: Preserves existing references to DOM elements when appending elements, Preserves event handlers attatched to any DOM elements and in some cases could be simpler and faster. It's a good idea to learn to use it, this is why I do like this in that case, because Brentix45 is starting learning deeply JS. In this case is faster your way(InnerHTML), but not better.

Comment: 1. I never have event handlers on multiple elements. That is what delegation is for.
2. If I need to copy elements later, I myself would CLONE the parent instead of your FOUR createElements. 3 I find the loop where you remove elements and then immediately add elements has a strong code smell. If I wanted to code this myself, I would consider having the structure already in the DOM and simply change the textContent of the elements which would be the fastest and have the least impact on DOM and memory

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you delegate and create an object to hold the values
Then you are much more DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)

I additionally use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
const radioContainer = document.getElementById("radioContainer");
const linkBase = 'https://join.meet.video.justice.gov.uk/HMCTS/#/';
const emailBase = '@meet.video.justice.gov.uk';
const output = document.getElementById("output");
const rooms = {
  "hmcts369": {
    "telephone": "02920 376411",
    "guestPin": "4444"
  },
  "hmcts453": {
    "telephone": "02920 376400",
    "guestPin": "5555"
  }
};

// create the room radios
radioContainer.innerHTML = Object
  .keys(rooms)
  .map(key => `<label><input type="radio" name="CVPRoom" />${key.toUpperCase()}</label>`).join("<br/>");
  
radioContainer.addEventListener("click", function(e) { // click anywhere in the label to select and show the details
  const tgt = e.target.closest("label");
  if (!tgt) return
  const thisRoom = tgt.textContent.trim();
  const thisRoomKey = thisRoom.toLowerCase();
  const details = rooms[thisRoomKey];
  if (!details) {
    alert(`Sorry, room ${thisRoom} not found`);
    return;
  }
  const href = `${linkBase}?conference=${thisRoomKey}${emailBase}`; //
  output.innerHTML = `<div  id="roomNo">CVP Room: ${thisRoom}</div>
  <div  id="phoneNo">Telephone Number: ${details.telephone}</div>
  <div  id="guestPin>Guest Pin Number: ${details.guestPin}</div>
  <div  id="roomLink"><a href="${href}"><b>Full Clickable URL Link</b></a></div>`;
})
```

```html
<div id="radioContainer"></div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Note the URL is not a truly valid URL with the /#/ in the middle.

If you have a better URL, you can do

```
const linkBase = new URL('https://join.meet.video.justice.gov.uk/HMCTS/#/'); // invalid URL - fix it and we can use the URL API
linkBase.searchParams.set("conference", `${thisRoomKey}${emailBase}`); // set the conference parameter
const href = linkBase.toString(); // get the URL
```

Here is a version that does not manipulate the DOM but just changes the text and attributes

```js
const radioContainer = document.getElementById("radioContainer");
const linkBase = 'https://join.meet.video.justice.gov.uk/HMCTS/#/';
const emailBase = '@meet.video.justice.gov.uk';
const output = document.getElementById("output");
const roomNo = document.getElementById("roomNo");
const phoneNo = document.getElementById("phoneNo");
const guestPin = document.getElementById("guestPin");
const roomLink = document.getElementById("roomLink");
const rooms = {
  "hmcts369": {
    "telephone": "02920 376411",
    "guestPin": "4444"
  },
  "hmcts453": {
    "telephone": "02920 376400",
    "guestPin": "5555"
  }
};

// create the room radios
radioContainer.innerHTML = Object
  .keys(rooms)
  .map(key => `<label><input type="radio" name="CVPRoom" />${key.toUpperCase()}</label>`).join("<br/>");

radioContainer.addEventListener("click", function(e) { // click anywhere in the label to select and show the details
  const tgt = e.target.closest("label");
  if (!tgt) return
  output.hidden = true;
  const thisRoom = tgt.textContent.trim();
  const thisRoomKey = thisRoom.toLowerCase();
  const details = rooms[thisRoomKey];
  if (!details) {
    alert(`Sorry, room ${thisRoom} not found`);
    return;
  }
  const href = `${linkBase}?conference=${thisRoomKey}${emailBase}`; //
  roomNo.textContent = thisRoom;
  phoneNo.textContent = details.telephone;
  guestPin.textContent = details.guestPin;
  roomLink.href = href;
  output.hidden = false;
})
```

```html
<div id="radioContainer"></div>
<div id="output" hidden>
  <div>CVP Room: <span id="roomNo"></span></div>
  <div>Telephone Number: <span id="phoneNo"></span></div>
  <div>Guest Pin Number: <span id="guestPin"></span></div>
  <div><a id="roomLink" href=""><b>Full Clickable URL Link</b></a></div>
</div>
```